# Check if pattern is found in matrix if yes return indices

Tags: python

INPUT:
first line take n value and pattern to be found
then input the matrix of characters
OUTPUT:
YES or NO if yes print indices also

### sample test case

3 apple
ppe
lad
ebz

#### output

Yes 2212112131

I've partially done the following code but not able to complete it..

```
    n = int(n)
    l=[]
    for i in range(n):
        x=input().split("")
        c=[]
        for j in range(n):
            c.append(x[j])
        l.append(c)

    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(n): 
            print(l[i][j], end = " ") 
        print() 

    list1 = list(string)   #this converts the pattern string into a list of characters
```

after this i'm not getting how to proceed. would be great if someone could help me out

Comment: What does the `2212112131` refer to and why aren't isn't there three outputs?

Comment: 22 refers to second row second element which is a.....we should check if the word apple is derived from the matrix and return the indices of each letter of the word present in the matrix